# How to save only some information to .log file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

I am trying to set up logging.
I have a class LoginAttemptService and I would like only logs from this class will be stored in logs.

```
@Service
public class LoginAttemptService {

    private final int MAX_ATTEMPT = 5;

    private LoadingCache<String, Integer> attemptsCache;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginAttemptService.class);

 public void loginSucceeded(String username, String key) {
        attemptsCache.invalidate(key);
        logger.info("Successful login:  " + username + " ip address:" + key);
    }
```

application properties:

```
logging.file = logfile.log
```

Problem now is, that everything is saved to that file... not only logins attempts

EDIT:
I created logback.xml file in my classpath with the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <appender name="login" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>log1.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <logger name="com.patrikmaryska.bc_prace.bc_prace.service.LoginAttemptService" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="login"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

But it still now saved to that file...

Comment: So what exactly you are looking for? A separate log file that only holds login attempts?

Comment: @cmlonder yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add logback.xml to your resources and configure appender.

And use following logger:

```
@Service
public class LoginAttemptService {

    private final int MAX_ATTEMPT = 5;

    private LoadingCache<String, Integer> attemptsCache;
    private static Logger loginLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("login");

    public void loginSucceeded(String username, String key) {
        attemptsCache.invalidate(key);
        loginLogger.info("Successful login:  " + username + " ip address:" + key);
    }
```

logback.xml:

```
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS_HOME" value="./logs/"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LOGIN-LOG"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS_HOME}login.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}login.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="login" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGIN-LOG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGIN-LOG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: do I need to have those .log files created before logging?

Comment: No, log files will be created aumatically by logger

Comment: it does not work for me... I coppied the whole configuration and added "logger" to my code, but those logs are not even created... :/

Comment: Could you check your working directory? The file (./logs/login.log) should be there.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I have just fixed the config. Please, try again.

Comment: still nothing :(

Comment: Do you use: 
    private static Logger loginLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("login");

Comment: I did not... but when I replaced it with private static (I had only private), the problem persists...:/

Comment: Dont I have to register it somehow? That i am using config file?

Comment: I have just created repo with sample. Please, clone and run the Application.java
https://github.com/ivan333m/logging.git

Comment: Have a look at FunRestController for usage sample.

Comment: thank you sir, it helped me a lot. The misstake was fairly stupid. :-) I did not have logback.xml in resource folder, but in the same place where pom.xml is... Its working now.